# Kubuntu white stripes Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, drivers, kubuntu

I made a clean installation of Ubuntu 12.04 and added the Kubuntu desktop. Now I have white stripes at the bottom of the desktop (in the task bar) they are paired and in a regular distance to each user.

Before this installation, I installed Kubuntu (directly), it did not have these stripes (and no working USB, therefore I choose to install Ubuntu first and add Kubuntu afterwords). 
I have a graphics card on the chip and an additional Nvidia card, which is not used as standard.

There are no drivers listed in 'additional drivers'. What could I do to 'remove' these stripes? They go away when clicking on the task bar or any other button.

My system specifications:

```
i7 3632qm
nvidia geforce 710M
16 gb memory
500 gb ssd
```

Thanks for an answer!

Here is a screenshot of the issue:

[image]

It seems that the stripes (and also the chosen background) disappear, when connecting a second screen. With a connected screen I have the typical Ubuntu background and no stripes.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a Nvidia driver issue. Try reinstalling them:

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
sudo reboot
```

Comment: unfortunately, the stripes are still there. But thank you for this suggestion.